# Screen glitches and unusable laptop after woken up

Tags: nvidia, suspend, screen

I have this issue that whenever my laptop is woken up after a **long time of being suspended** the screen goes white and does some weird glitches and is unable to use. It is fixed after a force-reboot but it gets annoying when I accidentally leave my laptop on suspend and I have to restart it later.

Any solution?

GPU: Geforce 310M (yes it is bad)

Comment: When it happens, try restarting gnome using `Alt+F2`, type `r` and press `Enter` to run.

Comment: didnt work
i tried to login before doing it but it didnt work.